# Access to old association inside Rails/ActiveRecord callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

In my Rails callback I have something like this:

```
private
def update_points
  if user_id_changed?
    user_was = User.find(user_id_was)
    user_was.points -= points_was
    user_was.save
    user.points += points
    user.save
  end
end
```

Is that the proper way to do this with `user_was`? I initially just assumed `user_was` was already defined (or could be defined on the spot) because `user_id_was` existed.

Comment: Are you getting any errors from that or is the output not what you expected? I couldn't get that from your question.

Comment: @depa - no errors, just seems like there should be a simpler way with Rails...

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me from the context what exactly you're doing (maybe the 2nd `points` is supposed to be `points_was`?).  For mildly improved clarity, depending on who you ask, and with fewer lines:

```
...
  user_was = User.find(user_id_was)
  user_was.update_column :points, user_was.points - points_was
  user.update_column     :points, user.points     + points
...
```